# Instantaneous axis of rotation and rolling cone motion

Tags: reference-frames, rotational-kinematics

Suppose a cone is purely rolling (no slipping) around a fixed axis. Elaborately, it is revolving around a fixed axis perpendicular to the ground and passing through its vertex and also rotating, and the vertex is stationary.

[image]

Now the instantaneous axis of rotation (IAR) of the cone is the 'line' that is touching the ground right? So how do you find the velocity of any other point using that? I mean, in the rolling wheel, you multiply the angular velocity by the distance from the IAR to get the velocity. Is it the same here?

If it is, then consider the center of base of the cone. If the height of cone is $h$ then its distance from the IAR is clearly $h\sin x$ where $x$ is the cone's half apex angle. So its velocity should be $ah\sin x$, where $a$ is the angular velocity with which the cone is rotating. Is this right?

Now we can also analyse the cone's motion by considering it in two parts: rotation + revolution, right? So again considering the center of base of the cone, it has no velocity by virtue of rotation (since the cone is rotating about an axis through the center), right? And by virtue of it rotating in a circle (of radius $h\cos x$) around the axis passing through its vertex, it has velocity $bh\cos x$ , where $b$ is the angular velocity with which the cone is revolving.

Now these two must be same, so we get $b=a \tan x$.

But Wikipedia states [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_cone_motion#Kinematics) that the ratio is $\sin x$.

And at the same time, [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6_n2FApGkAE) video (which I found in the external links section of the Wikipedia page) states that $a=b\cot x$ which is same as what I got.

I'm really confused. Is everything that I did right? If not please correct me. Thank you.

How to find velocity of any point on the  cone? There ought to be two approaches , one using IAR and another by considering motion as rotation + revolution but I'm not able to do it.

Comment: The wikipedia article describes a cone rolling on a cone. You apparently are trying to describe a cone rolling on a plane.

Comment: @DavidHammen Yes but it also says " In the special case of a cone rolling on a flat surface, this ratio becomes sin alpha, where alpha is the cone's half apex angle"

Comment: Well, (thought experiment) how is the instantaneous linear velocity of the center of the cone's base different from the velocity of the center of a rolling disk?  Solve that and convert into angular velocity about the vertex of the cone, maybe.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Oh , so the cone's base is like a rolling disk but it is touching the ground at an angle. If that angle is theta then I'd guess linear velocity of center to be um $w*r*sin(theta)$, is that right? edit: Now I'm thinking it's just $w*r$, hmm.

Comment: @AGoogler See my revised answer. I believe I've found my mistake: I divided $\cos$ by $\sin$ and somehow got $\tan$, whereas it should of course have been $\cot$! Now the answer makes a great deal more sense. The computation is exactly as you say: the instantaneous axis is along the contact plane and you multiply $h\sin\alpha$ by the instantaneous angular speed.

Answer (score 10):

Let the cone lie on the $\hat{X}\wedge \hat{Y}$ plane (z=0) and let the $z$ axis pierce this plane at the cone's apex. If the cone's half angle is $\alpha$, then its axis of symmetry as a function of time is defined by the vector

$$A(t)=\cos\alpha \left(\cos(\omega_0\,t) \hat{X} + \sin(\omega_0\,t) \hat{Y}\right)+\sin\alpha \hat{Z}$$

where $\omega_0 = 2\pi/\tau$ and $\tau$ is time it takes the cone to make exactly one circuit on the $\hat{X}\wedge \hat{Y}$ plane. Thus the cone's axis of symmetry rotates with angular velocity $\omega_0\,\hat{Z}$. I define my directions and symbols below:

[image: Rolling Cone]

If the cone doesn't slip, this means that the rotation about the axis $A(t)$ has an angular velocity $- \omega_0 A(t)/\sin\alpha$. Sketch the cone near the apex to see this: at a distance $R$ along the edge (defined by the vector $\cos(\omega_0\,t) \hat{X} + \sin(\omega_0\,t) \hat{Y}$) in the $\hat{X}\wedge \hat{Y}$ plane where the cone meets the plane, the tip of this edge moves at speed $v_e=\omega_0\,R$. The circular cone cross section (orthogonal to the cone's axis of rotational symmetry) through this point is like a wheel of radius $r=R\,\sin\alpha$ cambered inwards at angle $\alpha$. This "wheel" must spin at angular velocity $-\omega_0\,R\,A(t)/r$ so that its rim's velocity is $-v_e=-\omega_0\,R$ to offset the velocity $v_e=\omega_0\,R$ of the edge at this point and keep the point of the wheel in contact with the ground stationary.

We add these two angular velocities to get:

$$\Omega(t) = \omega_0\left(\hat{Z} - \frac{A(t)}{\sin\alpha}\right)=-\omega_0 \,\cot\alpha\,\left(\cos(\omega_0\,t) \hat{X} + \sin(\omega_0\,t) \hat{Y}\right)$$

which, as you correctly guessed, is always along the line where the cone meets the plane.

The instantaneous speed of a point on the cone's axis of symmetry a distance $h$ from the base is $|\Omega|\,h\,\sin\alpha = \omega_0\,h\,\cot\alpha\,\sin\alpha = \omega_0 \,h\,\cos\alpha$ ($|\Omega|$ times as you say, the orthogonal distance $h\,\sin\alpha$ of the point from the instantaneous axis of rotation.

Note that we get the same answer by simply working this speed out for an angular velocity $\omega_0\,\hat{Z}$, which is valid because the axis of the cone has no velocity owing to the rotation in the direction $A(t)$. The point on the cone's axis of symmetry is a distance $h\,\cos\alpha$ from the $\hat{Z}$ axis. Thus the speed is, as before, $\omega_0\,h\,\cos\alpha$.

Comment: Hi , thanks for the answer. Your notation and way of solving the problem was a bit new for me but I'm trying to understand. A few questions:

Comment: 1. the final angular velocity is wtanx along the contact line. So if i wanted to find velocity of any point on the cone , would i just multiply wtanx by the perpendicular distance of that point from the line? 2. If so then velocity of centre of base of cone would be hsinx*wtanx where h is height. But it should be hcosx*w since hcosx is distance from z axis and centre has no velocity due to rotation of cone. Please help,I'm confused.

Comment: @AGoogler  Let me come back to this: am a little busy at the moment: can see your problem and there must be a difference between our notations somewhere.

Comment: @AGoogler Still haven't forgotten about you. I'll be mulling over your question over the weekend - sometimes I do a great deal of slow thinking whilst watching my children play, and I'll take your problem with me.

Comment: Thanks , your help is really appreciated. Meanwhile can you suggest a good physics book for me ? (mostly classical mechanics , rotational mechanics with an emphasis on problem solving)

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much. So , I guess the fault in my original reasoning ( 3rd and 4th paragraph) was that for all objects , total angular velocity will always be along IAR , but it's magnitude is generally not equal to the angular velocity with which the object is rotating( or it is only equal in case of a rolling wheel) .

Comment: After thinking more , I guess to easily find magnitude of total angular velocity along IAR we can just take component of angular velocity with which the object in rotating(w/sinx in this case) in the direction of IAR ( so in this case we'll get w/sinx * cosx = wcotx) . Is that right?

Comment: [Herbert Goldstein's Classical Mechanics](http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Mechanics-Edition-Herbert-Goldstein/dp/0201657023) is a good one, and has a very good treatment of this situation.

Comment: @AGoogler I don't feel qualified to cite a good text. I learnt this stuff a long time ago and nowadays study it from a Lie theoretic standpoint, so I tend to work things out from first principles. I was first taught this stuff from engineering texts, which are dreadful. I had to go to [Landau and Lifshitz](http://www.amazon.com/Mechanics-Third-Course-Theoretical-Physics/dp/0750628960/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1413169156&sr=1-1&keywords=Mechanics+Landau) was where I ended up going, but this is very old. Here's a version of ...

Comment: ..[Goldstein (the reference suggested by @rmhleo)](http://www.amazon.com/Classical-Mechanics-Edition-Herbert-Goldstein/dp/0201657023) with a "look inside". The material covered does look like an excellent selection, but I can't review this book in detail.

Comment: Very nicely done.

Comment: Hey , can you address my question on comment no. 6&7? Sorry if that is too much to ask.

Comment: @SeleneRoutley Fantastic answer,+1. Although I have some confusions