# Proving that the angular velocity of a rigid body is the same about any point

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, rotation, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

Please consider the below image which is from Rana and Joag, Classical Mechanics. They build on a proof, which I reiterate below and through it they show that angular velocity of any point B in the rigid body is the same about a point $B_0$ and then state that the angular velocity of B is same about any other point too.

[image]

From the image above and considering the rigid body constraints we get,

$\pmb{{\rho_1}\times (\dot{\rho_1}\times \dot{\rho_2} )} = \pmb{(\rho_1 . \dot{\rho_2})\dot{\rho_1}} - \pmb{(\rho_1 . \dot{\rho_1})\dot{\rho_2}} = -\pmb{(\rho_2 . \dot{\rho_1})\dot{\rho_1}}$

which implies that

$\pmb{ \dot{\rho_1} = (\frac{\dot{\rho_1}\times\dot{\rho_2}}{\dot{\rho_1} . \rho_2})}\times \rho_1 $

and similarly we can get

$\pmb{ \dot{\rho_2} = (\frac{\dot{\rho_1}\times\dot{\rho_2}}{\dot{\rho_1} . \rho_2})}\times \rho_2 $

The book says " that the above equations indicate that the vector

$\pmb{ \omega = (\frac{\dot{\rho_1}\times\dot{\rho_2}}{\dot{\rho_1} . \rho_2})}$

behaves as an angular velocity vector for $\pmb{\rho_1}$ and $\pmb{\rho_2}$ about $B_0$. The book proves that the any given point in the body say **B** has the same angular velocity as given by the expression but doesn't prove that why any point in the body should have the **same angular velocity about any other point** say **$B_0'$**.

This is what I want to prove **mathematically rigorously**. To do that I begin writing

$\pmb{ \rho_1 = \rho_1' + a}$ and similarly $\pmb{ \rho_2 = \rho_2' + a}$ and I try to find their time derivative and substitute the result into the expression for $\pmb{\omega}$ that has been calculated above. Now I will get my correct answer only if

$\pmb{\dot{a}} = 0$

Now I don't think that $\pmb{\dot{a}} = 0$ should be true because the **direction of a will change even if its magnitude is constant** and hence I fail to prove the result.

Could anyone help me how to proceed forward using the above expression for $\pmb{\omega}$ to prove that it is indeed the same about any point in the body. Should $\pmb{\dot{a}} = 0$  be true because if it is false then the result is false itself. *But then why should be $\pmb{\dot{a}} = 0$  be true*.

Or is there another way out.

Comment: I could write the Landau-Lifshitz argument, but it's so short, and in general you would benefit much more if you directly read/work out the book. I recommend the latter. If you do that, you'd also see that for linear rigid bodies the proof doesn't go through...

Comment: @Vivek ok. Any fault you could see in this one. Or how should I proceed in this proof along the lines of my argument

Comment: @Vivek that is, will $\dot{a}$ be 0 or not...

Comment: "The book says " that the above equations indicate that the vector" I think this is wrong: $\omega=\frac{v\times R}{R\cdot R}$ check the units for omega $\frac{m/s\,m}{m^2}$

Comment: @Eli yes you can have a look at that equation for omega, it gives the units of omega as $\frac{m/s}{m}$, the same as which your equation for omega gives. It gives the same units, isn't it... Have a look at the equation and let me know please.

Comment: My fault sorry  for that

Comment: @Eli so you have any idea as to how to solve this problem. Can you help me out in this..

Comment: @Shashaank you find the solution here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity  “Consistency”

Comment: @Eli thank you Eli.. Finally I got it. But just a thing more, if you could help please. I got the wilkipedia... But then in the above case - it is not then necessary that $\dot{a}$ be 0, right. $\dot{a}$ can be non zero too, right.........

Comment: @Shashaank $\dot a_B=0$ but $\dot a_O\ne 0$

Comment: @Eli yes I got it, thank you Eli. BTW, are you doing a phd or already have one. In which country did you do your phd or are doing....

Comment: @Shashaank I did my Dr.-Ing. longtime ago in Germany

Comment: @Eli oh nice.. Nice talking to you..can I ask you for help incase I have any other problem in any other question by tagging you.

Comment: @Eli and also if you can suggest of a good text in rigid body dynamics and rotation apart from Landau, a one which is good from the point of view of physics..

Comment: @Eli  ok thank you. I had a small question. If you could please let me know how do we figure out the angular velocity of a rigid body. Suppose we choose the body coordinate system at the centre of mass ( or say any other point in the body), then how will we figure out the angular velocity of the rigid body. If suppose we know the instantaneous axis of rotation and the velocity of a point of the rigid body then we can calculate the angular velocity very easily. But if we don't know the instantaneous axis of rotation, is there any way to calculate the angular velocity of the body...

Comment: @Eli should I ask a separate question where you would like to answer  this or can you answer it here..

Comment: @Shashaank prof w. schiehlen Applied dynamics this book is mostly for Ingenieur, look also on the subject “multi body system” you find many books deals with rigid body

Comment: @Eli ok thanks a lot  Eli. I will look at those books thanks for that. Could you answer the doubt I had in the above comment. Should I ask a new question regarding that which you would like to answer or can you help me with as a extended comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Euler's theorem we know that a rigid motion in odd number of dimensions with one point fixed is a pure rotation about an axis (cf. Goldstein). This allows one to write,

$$\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r}) = \mathbf{v}_A + \omega_A \times(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_A), \quad \quad (1) $$

$$\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{r}) = \mathbf{v}_B + \omega_B \times(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_B). \quad \quad (2)$$

Now the velocity fields described by equation (1) and (2) must be the same. This means, in particular, that

$$ \omega_A \times \mathbf{r} = \omega_B \times \mathbf{r}.$$

The only way this is possible is if the vectors of angular velocity are equal, i.e. $\omega_A = \omega_B$, unless the rigid body is linear, in which case there is no way to uniquely define the angular velocity since rotations along the line which contains the rigid body do not contribute to physical motion.

Comment: So will $\dot{a}$ be 0 in my proof above or not.

Comment: No, why would it be? It's the relative velocity of $B'_0$ wrt $B_0$.

Comment: because if it isn't then I will get the wrong result. See if $\omega$ has to be same then $\dot{a}$ should be zero and my proof is exactly along the lines of landau. It's just a translation. We are unable to see why it should be 0...but if the result has to be true then it should be

Comment: Then that indicates a flaw in your reasoning or calculation somewhere...

Comment: can you figure out the fault then. I can accept your answer then if you can reiterate the fault.......

Comment: Don't accept my answer. It doesn't follow your route of reasoning. I just suggested an alternative simpler method assuming Euler's theorem. So I'd suggest you to wait for an answer that deals with the problem in the way you like.

Comment: As a side not since you have seen my question could you please tell me if the angular velocity is the same even if the axis is outside the body or not...

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter where the instantaneous axis of rotation passes through. The problem is about how to decompose motion into rotation and translation, and this can be done in infinitely many ways, depending on where you want to place your instantaneous axis of rotation.

Comment: ok thanks I understand your point completely, but I guess there is a difference in our terminoligies. By Euler's theorem any rigid body motion can be treated as a translation of a point in the rigid body and a rotation about an axis through any point in the body. In my last comment I meant can this axis be outside the body too. I guess you referred to that. If you can choose an axis such that it's translational velocity is 0 then it's called an instanataneous axis ie pure rotation about it. Now by writing " instantaneous" I guess you are meaning what I am saying. Kindly confirm thisfact

Comment: also see this - you can decompose the rotation and translation about any point but to find the instantaneous axis is a difficult problem ( which is the contact point of a sphere rolloing on ground, but you can have an axis through any point in sphere like centre of mass). You need to drop 2 perpendiculars etc.. But suppose you choose your inertial frame at the Center of Mass ( or any point inside) , then that point has 0 translational velocity wrt to the inertial frame and thus it will be a pure rotation about this point, ie and instantaneous axis.

Comment: continuing like this you can have infinite instantaneous axis of rotations by choosing the origin of your frame at the point about which you want to describe your rotation axis. Do you agree to this or not. Like to analyze the rolling sphere sit at its center of mass to get 0 translational velocity in that frame and a pure rotation. But if instanataneous axis of rotation can be infinite then why take the trouble of finding one by the procedure of dropping perpendiculars. Just choose a frame moving with the body to get a pure rotation and all is done. Is this wrong or right

Comment: I guess it's right and you are also suggesting just this but could you just confirm if what I have said above is true or not. Sorry for the repeated questions but if you could confirm, would be very helpful..

Comment: @Shashaank My bad, I should have not used the word "instantaneous" (it has a very specific meaning).

Comment: yes that's right but do you agree that another way ( instead of dropping perpendiculars etc) to find instantaneous axis of rotation is to just swtich to a moving frame where translational velocity becomes 0 and only a pure rotation remains. Is that another correct way or not.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can translate with any point on the rigid body and only a residual rotation of the rigid body will remain. This rotation is the same no matter what choice of point you make to travel alongside (hence the concept of "angular velocity" without reference to a specific point on the rigid body).

Comment: pardon me. But please let me know this. If like you said I am correct then why do we find inst. axis by dropping perpendiculars from two point etc and not by this way.. Also for a sphere rolling inside another sphere. Take the point about which translational and rotational velocity have to be decomposed outside the sphere. All answers then come wrong. So can this point about which decomposition can be done be taken outside the body or not. And secondly in this decomposition does the body coordinate system rotates with the body or is it's axis fixed in space parallel to the inertial axis

Comment: and lastly... The omega's magnitude is same what ever point in the body we choose. Say for a cone rolling, the instantaneous axis is along the direction of the curved surface of the cone ( not along the axis of the cone) if we take the center of mass as our point about which we wish to decompose the motion, the what will be the direction of omega, will it be same as before. Sorry for repeated questions but could you please help in these regards. If you wish I can ask a new question but would be helpful if you could answer in these regards

Comment: Mail me through the comment section on my blog (the link to which I posted in a comment to the previous question by satan). Can answer all your questions over a single call instead.

Comment: I have commented on your post there on your blog. I hope you get an email. If not you can contact me shashaank308@gmail.com   .... Looking forward to hear from you...

Comment: indeed a call would be good to settle all of my doubts... Let me know the next step...

Comment: so did you get my mail... I had commented on the post... So could you help me out in that....