# Proving the constancy of a vector in a rotating frame

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors, rotation

Suppose $r$ and $r'$ are the distances of a point P from points A and B in a rotating rigid body ( all points A, B, P are inside the rigid body). Now I can choose the body coordinate system whose origin lies at A or B ( or any point inside the body).

Let the distance between A and B be $a$, then,

$r=r' +a$.
Now what will be the derivative of $r$ will it be $\dot{r} = \dot{r'} $ that is will the time derivative of $a$ be 0 or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

you have three points on a rigid body.

$$\vec{R}_P\,,\vec{R}_A\,,\vec{R}_B$$

thus

$$\vec{r}=\vec{R}_A-\vec{R}_P$$
$$\vec{r}'=\vec{R}_B-\vec{R}_P$$
and
$$\vec{a}=\vec{r}-\vec{r}'=\vec{R}_A-\vec{R}_B$$

If only point P is changing  with the time t;  $\vec{R}_P=\vec{R}_p(t)$  thus $\vec{\dot{a}}=0$ , but if the body is rotate about axis that goes throw   point P  thus
$\quad \vec{\dot{a}}=\vec{\dot{\varphi}}\times \vec{a}=\dot{\varphi}\,\hat{\vec{u}}$ , where $\varphi=\varphi(t)$ is the rotation angle about the axis $\hat{\vec{u}}=\frac{\vec{u}}{\sqrt{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}}}$

so any rotation axis $\hat{\vec{u}}$ that not parallel to vector $\vec{a}$ , the components of $\vec{\dot{a}}$ are not zero

**edit**

first you transform the components of vector a from B frame to O frame

$$\vec{a}_O=S\,\vec{a}_B$$

where S is the rotation matrix.

take the time derivative

$$\vec{\dot{a}}_O= \left[\frac{d}{dt}\,S\right]\,\vec{a}_B$$

For the rotation matrix I use the Rodriguez matrix

$$S=I_3+\sin(\varphi)\,\tilde{u}+(1-\cos(\varphi))\,\tilde{u}\,\tilde{u}$$

where

$$\tilde{u}=\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-u_{{z}}&u_{{y}}\\ u_{
{z}}&0&-u_{{x}}\\ -u_{{y}}&u_{{x}}&0\end {array}
 \right] 
$$

and the rotation axis :
$$\vec{u}\mapsto \frac{\vec{u}}{\sqrt{\vec{u}\cdot\vec{u}}}=\begin{bmatrix}
  u_x \\
  u_y \\
  u_z \\
\end{bmatrix}_B$$

thus

$$\dot{S}=\dot{\varphi}\cos(\varphi)\,\tilde{u}+\dot{\varphi}\sin(\varphi)\,\tilde{u}\,\tilde{u}$$

thus:

$$\vec{\dot{a}}_O= \dot{S}\,\vec{a}_B=
 \dot{\varphi}\left[\cos(\varphi)\,\tilde{u}+\sin(\varphi)\,\tilde{u}\,\tilde{u}\right]\,\vec{a}_B$$

so if $\vec{{u}}\parallel \vec{a}\quad$  the components of  $\vec{\dot{a}}_O$ are equal zero.

with $\tilde{u}\,\vec{a}=\vec{\hat{u}}\times \vec{a}$

Comment: I don't know if can agree with your last line. $\dot{a}$ should always be 0 if a body is rotating otherwise then the angular velocity will not remain constant... See this question of mine to see why - https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/559207/113699

Comment: What if the rotation axis passes through A or B... Will then $\dot{a}$ be 0 or not

Comment: @Shashaank in this case you are right $\dot a=0$ But only in this case

Comment: yes precisely in this case. But I just know it should be 0 but I cannot intuitively imagine as to why it should be 0. It was precisely in this case I wanted to know why it should be 0.  Could you please add a few lines as to what reason will you give for it being 0 in **this case**. I will accept the answer.

Comment: @Shashaank please look new comment

Comment: thanks I have accepted it. Just 2 things more. You write - "if the rotation axis is the vector a" but in **this specific case** the rotation axis passes through either A or B and a is just the displacement vector between A and B.... So what do you mean by that line... And why did you write $\dot{a}_o = d/dt [ S] a_B$ and not $\dot{a}_o = d/dt [Sa_b]... Please let me know these points.

Comment: Vector a goes from point B to point A , look at the figure. The components of this vector in B system are constant, but not in O system. $a_O=S\,a_B $ ,so take the time derivative of this equation ,you obtain $\dot a_O=\dot S\,a_B$

Comment: ok thanks.. I understood that... But you write "if the rotation axis is the vector a" I am just saying that rotation axis will be perpendicular to the body passing through either A or B... So why do you write that-  if rotation axis is the vector a.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you

Comment: so what will be the corresponding correct statement in your answer. Will it affect your answer

Comment: No, the results is the same for, any parallel axis to AB

Comment: and what if the axis is perpendicular to the body and passes through A... Then also will the result be same or not.

Comment: And if you wish to add an answer to this question too -https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/559207/113699 for the sake of completeness, I will accept it, for sure