# Why is the angular speed at the axis of rotation of a rotating disc equal to the angular speed at any other point on the disc?

Tags: rotational-kinematics, calculus, angular-velocity

I was just reviewing classical mechanics problems on Khan Academy and got the following question:

[image]

I knew that the angular speeds at points II, III, and IV must be equal, but I'm not sure how you'd prove that the angular speed at point I is equal as well, since the usual formula $ω=\frac{v}{r}$ just gives $ω=\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: "Angular speed" (a.k.a., [_angular velocity_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_velocity)) isn't a measure of distance travelled per unit time, It's a measure of rotation rate. It's measured in radians per second (or cycles per second, or degrees per second, or RPM.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow Right, but how does a point at the axis of rotation even have a rotation rate?

Comment: Are you asking because a "point" is dimensionless? Because we can't tell which way it is facing? But the disk in which the point is embedded is not dimensionless, and we _can_ mark it, and so be able to tell which way it is facing.

Comment: Your confusing tangential velocity with angular velocity

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yes, exactly. If the point is dimensionless and exactly on the axis of rotation, then in what way does that point sweep out an angle over time with respect to the axis of rotation? With all other points on the disc, I can imagine them tracing out angles over time because they're some distance from the axis, and therefore their angular position with respect to the axis changes over time. Point I, on the other hand, never changes angular position with respect to the axis.

Comment: Duplicate [Proving that the angular velocity of a rigid body is the same about any point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/559207/proving-that-the-angular-velocity-of-a-rigid-body-is-the-same-about-any-point)

Answer (score 0):

The point of the question is to demonstrate that the angular velocity $\omega$ of the spinning disk, measured from it's centre, is the same for all points on the disk. You can imagine placing an infinitely long rod parallel to the plane of the disc, with one end of the rod positioned at the centre of the disk and the other end infinitely far away. When the disk is spinning, the rod sweeps out an angle $\phi$ at all points of the rod (including the point at the centre of the disk). Now the angular velocity is the rate of change of $\phi$ with respect to time:$$\omega=\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}.$$Notice how $\phi$ has only $t$ dependence. To show that this is the same for all points on the disk, let $r$ be the distance from the centre of the disk to some point on the disk. Now taking the derivative of $\omega$ with respect to $r$ gives us$$\frac{d\omega}{dr}=\frac{d}{dr}\left(\frac{d\phi(t)}{dt}\right)=0.$$This means that $\omega$ is the same for all points on the disk (analogous to the infinite rod sweeping out the same angle along every point).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand why all points on a rigid disc have the same angular velocity, but I still don't understand how that could be true of the point right at the axis of rotation. This point seems to be unique: since there is zero distance between it and the axis, it doesn't sweep out an angle with respect to the axis as the disc rotates. Is there a more sophisticated definition of angular velocity that I'm missing? Also, is the 'dr' inside the parentheses in the second equation supposed to be 'dt'?

Comment: Yes, I made a correction. I have already proved that angular velocity is the same regardless of the distance from the centre. But intuitively, you can imagine rather than a point at the centre, a cylinder. Then as the disk spins, so does the cylinder, sweeping out the respective angle.

Comment: But then wouldn't that destroy the zero-dimensionality of the point? Is there another way to intuitively understand it?

Comment: I do not think that the point at the center has a well-defined angular velocity. Imagine the 'disc' consists only of that point. Then we could not even tell whether it rotates or not. It is probably just a matter of convenience to define the angular velocity of that point being the same as of any other point. It is a rigid body after all. So that is the most sensible convention.

Comment: @KurtG. That's what I was thinking. However, I can't seem to find a source stating this explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, you are right that the angular velocity of the zero-dimensional centre point is not defined. This is expressed in the formula you provide, where you approach a zero denominator.

Physically though, to all practical purposes, the centre point can be considered as rotating - you can imagine zooming in down to the centre atom and still define such rotation. From a physical perspective you can argue that every point rotates at the same angular velocity, not just based on the given formula, but simply from the perspective of the object being idealised as perfectly rigid. For a rigid physical object, the angular velocity of any point is equal in order to maintain the material bonds from the definition of rigid.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I still feel that this kind of answer is unsatisfying, since the question concerns points, which are defined as zero-dimensional and not just very tiny pockets of space. Therefore, if we are talking about an actual zero-dimensional point, I don't see how the angular velocity could be defined. That point is not rotating with respect to itself, no? I don't see how it could be meaningful to speak of the rotation of a zero-dimensional object with respect to itself.