# Rotation question: is my method of approach correct?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

**This question is very famous and asked many times, but I want to discuss some another aspect of this question and not something which has been asked before**

**I want to know if my method of approach is correct?**

[image: question image]VfYn0.jpg

I tried to solve the total angular momentum about the origin and I want to know if my method of approach is correct or not.

Here is my approach:

1. There are two rotations happening around the origin, one that is a revolution of discs around their axis (rod) and another one revolving around the origin
   Therefore I have to take two angular momentum on these two rotation and add them, to get the total angular momentum of the origin

And my another problem is that I have seen videos of famous YouTube teachers but they don't count these two rotation and only take one rotation

https://youtu.be/8QnUl9sqTRQ?si=8qiJYUd2PmDMPleV

This is the link to the video

If there is any mistake, I am sorry for that, but please help me out with this one, i tried my best

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rolling without slipping, general analysis](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/656811/)